# how to save the input value of sweetalert in database and how to move row from table to another

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

i'm new to Laravel and coding
i have a page that contain tabs and each tab has a table
[as you can see in the picture][1]
the active tab has a table and when i click on a row a sweetalert popup appear for a confirmation of the row selected, when i click the confirm button another popup sweetalert appear and ask the user to write truck number
what i want to do is: [picture 2][2]
**1- do a condition to the input of sweetalert (the form of truck number "XXX TU YYYY"
2- save the input into the database [enter image description here][3]
3- when you finish this the row selected will go from that tab and goes to the next tab**
***the DB name: PFE
the table name: fournisseursjour***
here's the code of the 2 popup msg in the blade:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.servipopupmsg').click(function(e){
  var namefourn = $(this).find(".namefourn").text( );
  e.preventDefault();
  swal("are you sure you want to continue with "+namefourn+"?  ", {
  buttons: ["Cancel ", "confirm "],
}).then((result) => {
  if( result){
    console.log("User confirmed!" );
    swal("Taper Matricule Camion:", {
    content: "input",
    })
    .then((value) => {
    console.log("Value to check for valid matricule: "+ value );
    });
  }else{
    console.log( "User Not confirmed!" );
  }
})
})
});
</script>
```

the code of the controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class FournisseursController extends Controller
{
    public function fournisseurP(){
        $data['data']=DB::table('fournisseursjour')->where('FCY_0', 'BAR')->get();
        if(count($data) > 0){
            return view('LogBook.FournisseurAziza', $data);
        }else{
            return view('LogBook.FournisseurAziza');
        }
    }
}
```

the route:

```
Route::get('/FournisseurAziza','FournisseursController@fournisseurP');
```

please help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTxzm.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnre6.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsD21.png

Comment: may be using ajax ?

Comment: tell me how i don't know how  really

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493898/sweetalert-confirm-with-ajax-request) post will be helpful